# Razor script in CSS

Tags: razor, razor-2, razorengine

I want to link to a file like I do in my View `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Is this possible in css?

Something like `background: url(@Url("~/Content/img/background.png"))`

Answer (score 0):

Razor view engine is parsing `.cshtml` files and evaluates the expression, output is clean html. Therefore you can't use the same engine to parse css files.

Possible solutions:

- keep the background on static location and hardcode it in css
- try to add `<style>` tag in `.cshtml` file and set the background from there, or add it via JS (not sure about the first one, but the second one should work)
- use SCSS preprocessor with Compass, it can pack assets (i.e. images) and you can reference them later, although it would be an overkill to use it just for this one background